# Synchronizing issues of MBO in SUP 2.1.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sybase, sup

I am trying to run an iOS application which is migrated from SUP2.1.2 to SUP2.1.3. An application is working fine with device registration and connection, but the problem arises when i try to synchronize 3 MBO synchronization group. The synchronization is working fine for the first time, but when i click over different item to synchronize its detail i am getting following error:

```
  *** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6465650
```

I think problem is coming under the following MBO method

```
 + (ITEMSSynchronizationParameters*)getSynchronizationParameters
 {
     return (ITEMSSynchronizationParameters*)[(SUPSyncParamEntityDelegate*)([[ITEMDATABASE delegate]           getDelegate:@"ITEMSSynchronizationParameters"]) getSynchronizationParameters];
 }
```

and i am calling this method while synchronizing app details as follows

```
    ITEMSynchronizationParameters *syncParam = [ITEMSynchronizationParameters getSynchronizationParameters];
    [syncParam setSYNC_NO:@"101"];
    [syncParam save];
```

While It also not allowing me to delete sync parameter so that on each items click i should get different information details as [syncParam delete] is causing the same *** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6465650 error. I have used patch 01 and 02 but the problem is still present. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same Problem.
In my case the answer for this problem was to create a locale property for the SynchronizationParameters and work with the Property. I don't know why but now the delicate error is gone.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ITEMSynchronizationParameters *item_sp;

 item_sp = [Item getSynchronizationParameters];
 item_sp.syncparam =  @"XXXXX";
 [item_sp save];
```